# How can I trust to self-signed certificate?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, apache-http-server, ssl

Hy! I want to have a valid padlock when I am accessing to a website. This need to be working only for me. Can I add a cert.crt file somewhere to don't have something like on the image below? Is this possible, if yes, how can I do it?

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrsA4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try 'this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/18602774#18602774) (or other answers in the same post). Let us know if one has worked for you.

Comment: You can do this by creating a minimal CA and adding your CA's root cert to your cert store, then using a cert generated by your CA on your website.  Without knowing your OS (and ideally browsee) its difficult to give precise instructions.

Comment: Thank You guys! That’s working for me. :)

Comment: @harrymc I have a one more error, I don't know what to do with "SubjectAltName". Do you know what I can do, because Chrome is blocking my full-trust secure connection?

Comment: Search for `SubjectAltName` in my linked post.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, you can’t trust a self-signed certificate since anybody can create one with any subject. However, if you create a certificate for your own site, you can trust it if you exchange it in a secure way (ssh/scp…) and import it in your navigator certificate store.

Creating a certificate is quite complexe with openssl. But Let’s encrypt can get a free third party (not self-signed) certificate and configure an Apache server to use it. You have to be the administrator of the server.

You should indicate your server configuration (Linux, Windows, Apache, Nginx, IIS…) since the installation of a certificate is different depending of the server.